# Same content show on every modals

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have tried to show the every student information on every modal. But every modals show the first student information. Please tell how to fix it.

```
    @foreach($data as $items)
          <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <div class="team-box">

                        <div class="team-img student-image" >
                          <img src="{{asset('photos' . $items->image)}}>
                          <span id="spanid1" hidden> {{ $items->name }}</span> 
                          <span id="spanid2" hidden> {{ $items->description }}</span> 
                       </div>
                       <div class="team-info">
                          <ul>
                              <li><b>Email</b>: {{ $items->email }}</li>
                              <li><b>Mobile</b>: {{ $items->$mobile }}</li>    
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
     @endforeach


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-name" id="myModalLabel">
                    </h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="modal-content">

                        </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>


    $(document).ready(function()
  {
       $('.student-image').on('click', function () 
        {
            var name = $("#spanid1").html();
            var description = $("#spanid2").html();

            if(description != '')
            {
                    $('#myModal').find('#modal-content').html(description);
                    $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').html(name);
            }

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
       });
  });
```

Comment: **id**'s should be unique on DOM, **class** is intended for reusability. Remember that! Hint: **span id="spanid1"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem where when you call 
`$("#spanid1").html()` this call the first item or student all the time because this is id must be unique.

must change to add a class for name and description

```
class="studentName"
class="studentDescription"
```

when the user click on model student-image get student name
get stuend name inside this ( this = when user click .student-image )

```
$('.studentName',this).html();
```

```
   @foreach($data as $items)
          <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <div class="team-box">

                        <div class="team-img student-image" >
                          <img src="{{asset('photos' . $items->image)}}>
                          <span id="spanid1" class="studentName" hidden> {{ $items->name }}</span> 
                          <span id="spanid2" class="studentDescription" hidden> {{ $items->description }}</span> 
                       </div>
                       <div class="team-info">
                          <ul>
                              <li><b>Email</b>: {{ $items->email }}</li>
                              <li><b>Mobile</b>: {{ $items->$mobile }}</li>    
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
     @endforeach


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-name" id="myModalLabel">
                    </h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="modal-content">

                        </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>


    $(document).ready(function()
  {
       $('.student-image').on('click', function () 
        {

            var name = $('.studentName',this).html();
            var description = $('.studentDescription',this).html();

            if(description != '')
            {
                    $('#myModal').find('#modal-content').html(description);
                    $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').html(name);
            }

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
       });
  });
```

Comment: Most elegant answer. I am oblige to you.